ROS internally calculated bandwidth for a topic is 10x smaller than actual bandwidth via iftop
We're transmitting camera feeds from a NVidia AGX Orin to a laptop and viewing with Foxglove. The camera feeds are analog NTSC captured with a frame grabber at 30Hz. We're using ROS Melodic and Ubuntu 20.04.6. The below table encapsulates the problem. We've tried three topics to transmit - Image/CompressedImage/CompressedVideo. Compressed video is a special encoding provided by foxglove. For some reason, the bandwidth to transmit this data is enormous, and doesn't pass the smell test for being a realistic outcome.
Table of bandwidths measured by ROS and measured by iftop:

I'm hoping someone has seen this before and can point me in the right direction to resolve the issue.

Hey there – could you provide more details about how you have set up the CompressedVideo encoding and transport? What are the quantity, resolutions, and framerates of your videos (to help estimate the expected total)? h.264 compression should provide a huge bandwidth reduction.
